# Появление текста если в json имеется этот элемент

Tags: php, json

у меня имеется php и json код, если в json коде написано `"Role":"member"` то не будет видно ни какого текста, а если будет `"Role":"admin"` то появится определённый текст

> $_COOKIE['accname'] это имя аккаунта.

```
   $json_data = file_get_contents("accounts/".$_COOKIE['accname'].".json");
    if(json_decode($json_data[$_COOKIE['accname']]['Role'] == 'admin')){
    
    /*code*/
    
      else{
        echo "Ошибка 1001" ;
    }
    }
```

json код

```
 {"AdminTV5":{
"Name":"AdminTV5",
"Password":"4c79713237da33a3ba91968864ff06af",
"Ban":false,
"Role":"admin"
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень похоже, что вы неправильно расставили скобки

```
 $json_data = file_get_contents("accounts/".$_COOKIE['accname'].".json");
 if(json_decode($json_data, true)[$_COOKIE['accname']]['Role'] == 'admin') {
    
     /*code*/
    
 }
 else {
     echo "Ошибка 1001" ;
 }
```